# How to retrieve all data from firebase. The current getData() function only retrieves one object

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm doing an firebase app for inputing and outputting data. I created a function that adds data to firebase and I want a function to print and update all the data on the website

I tried a function but it only retrieves the last object and I want all of them.

```js
function getData(){

    firebase.database().ref("/").on('value', function(snapshot){
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
        var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        document.getElementById("Data").innerHTML = childData['name'] + childData['age'];


      })
    })
  }
```

The data in the firebase looks like that:

```
Database
|
|-JOHN
|  name: JOHN|
|  age: 45
|
|-JANE
   name: Jane
   age: 39
```

[image: THIS IS THE SCREENSHOT OF MY DATABASE]

The function `writeData()` only retrieves the name and age for JANE.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your database structure

Comment: @ConstantinBeer I added the screenshot to the description

Comment: Did you tried to log with a `console.log()` before your `document.getElementById...` line? Do you also get only JANE back?

Comment: I added console.log() and nothing changed In the case of that function I only get the LAST object and I want all of them.

Comment: Basically I want a list that will append itself every time something is added to the database so that it displays everything from the database. @ConstantinBeer

Comment: That's strange. Your code looks ok. Only thing is the `.ref("/")` you always get the last data so I don't think that `.ref()` will get you another result.

Answer (score 1):

Each iteration of your `snapshot.forEach` is completely replacing the existing contents of the `Data` element in the HTML. So at the end of that loop, you'll just have the last item from the database in there.

The simplest fix is to clear the element before the loop, and then append the contents on each iteration:

```
firebase.database().ref("/").on('value', function(snapshot){
  let elm = document.getElementById("Data");
  elm.innerHTML = '';

  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
    var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();
    elm.innerHTML += childData['name'] + childData['age'];
  })
})
```